# Jquery get table row count ignoring row with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get table rows count ignoring all rows with a class?

I tried the below to get all rows count from a table with certain class. This works fine.

```
var rows= $('#myTable tbody tr.MyClass').length;
```

When I tried to find rows length for table which do not have that class, I tried the below but it did not return correct count? What may be the issue

```
var rows= $('#myTable tbody tr:not(.MyClass)').length;
```

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dL7j6c4s/. Check that the case of your class selector matches exactly.

Comment: Maybe try using `.not('.selector')`

Comment: `var rows= $('#myTable tbody tr').not('.myClass').length;`

Answer (score 3):

maybe:

```
var rows= $('#myTable tbody tr').not('.MyClass').length;
```